# Is there an implementation of Hadley's ddply for python?

Tags: python, r, plyr

I find Hadley's [plyr](http://had.co.nz/plyr/) package for R extremely helpful, its a great DSL for transforming data. The problem that is solves is so common, that I face it other use cases, when not manipulating data in R, but in other programming languages.

Does anyone know if there exists an a module that does a similar thing for python? Something like:

```
def ddply(rows, *cols, op=lambda group_rows: group_rows):
    """group rows by cols, then apply the function op to each group
       and return the results aggregating all groups
       rows is a dict or list of values read by csv.reader or csv.DictReader"""
    pass
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to implement, but would be great if it already existed. I'd implement it, I'd use `itertools.groupby` to group by `cols`, then apply the `op` function, then use itertools.chain to chain it all up. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the implementation I drafted up:

```
def ddply(rows, cols, op=lambda group_rows: group_rows): 
    """group rows by cols, then apply the function op to each group 
    rows is list of values or dict with col names (like read from 
    csv.reader or   csv.DictReader)"""
    def group_key(row):                         
        return (row[col] for col in cols)
    rows = sorted(rows, key=group_key)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        op(group_rows) for k,group_rows in itertools.groupby(rows, key=group_key))
```

Another step would be to have a set of predefined functions that could be applied as `op`, like `sum` and other utility functions.

Comment: The `operator` module may be handy for your premade functions.

Comment: If you could write this on top of the pandas python module then you might win the internet (in my eyes, at least)

Comment: @MikeDewar: Is there a pandas implementation of this?

Comment: I use Pandas' pivot_table function http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I am just trying to reduce a frame into its group, and creating a list containing the grouped columns. Let's say I have a data frame with the meals I eat over the each day of a week over the entire month. I wish I could group it per week day, and make a list of all the meals, e.g. Monday: [eggs, milk, pasta]. How could I do this in python?